# Xcode Version Controll GIT - has uncommitted changes, just after commit

Tags: xcode, git

when i commit the changes i made in my project in Xcode, and then want to push them onto the server, xcode says i would have uncommitted changes, but I was just committing...

Therefor I can not push or pull to the server :-(

i do not have enough reputation to post image so i uploaded it to imageshack http://imageshack.us/a/img268/7136/bildschirmfoto20120924u.png

i already added .dsstore files to the .gitignore

Thank you!

Comment: can you check using the command line? `git status` will give you more information.

Comment: ok did that status thing when the error appears again:

Comment: # On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
# modified:   .DS_Store
#

But .gitignore is:

.DS_Store
build/
*.pbxuser
xcuserdata/

Comment: You may have added .DS_Store to the repo before you ignored it. This creates a bunch of hassle. Try `git rm .DS_Store` and commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i think i got it. Xcode does not list hidden files like .DS_Store so I had to remove the file from version control with `git rm --cached .DS_Store`. `git status` made my day thanks

Comment: Where do you put that command. In other words, What is the directory where that command has to be runned? Thanks!!

Comment: Hey just in the root directory of the project that is under version controll. Where git status gives you a meaningful answer ;)