# Xcode: "The working copy ____ has uncommitted changes" vs. git status: "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Tags: xcode, git

In Xcode 5.0.2, I try to pull from a remote and am given the following message:

"The working copy 'project-name' has uncommitted changes. Commit or discard the changes and try again."

Fair enough. I pull up the commit dialog, and am then given the message, "This file does not exist at the requested revision." Clicking 'OK' brings me on into the commit dialog. (There is no revision displayed in the right pane, presumably for the same reason I was given the most recent message.) Selecting the flat view, I see that there is only one modified file: `project.pbxproj`. I enter a commit message and click 'Commit 1 File'. When I then go to pull, I find that I am in exactly the same position as before--the same messages appear and I am unable to pull (or push) no matter how many times I make a commit.

Curious, I run `git diff` to see *just* what has changed. Nothing. `git status` provides me with equally helpful output: `nothing to commit, working directory clean`. `git push` or `git pull`? Yep, those work just fine from the command line.

So what gives? Why does Xcode insist that I have changes in my working directory? Why won't it tell me what they are? Have tried restarting Xcode and system. While I'm happy that I still have *some* way to push and pull, it would be really nice if the Xcode git integration was behaving nicely. Any ideas?

I've found these similar questions, but none address this particular issue (or provide an acceptable solution):

- [Cannot push, pull or merge git. "Working copy has uncommited changes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910228/cannot-push-pull-or-merge-git-working-copy-has-uncommited-changes)
- [Commit or discard the changes and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147433/commit-or-discard-the-changes-and-try-again)
- [Git pull fails: You have unstaged changes. Git status: nothing to commit (working directory clean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368818/git-pull-fails-you-have-unstaged-changes-git-status-nothing-to-commit-workin)
- [Xcode Version Controll GIT - has uncommitted changes, just after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570098/xcode-version-controll-git-has-uncommitted-changes-just-after-commit)
- [Xcode says "Uncommitted Changes" Whenever I try to git pull or push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173261/xcode-says-uncommitted-changes-whenever-i-try-to-git-pull-or-push)

Comment: Would a `git reset --hard` help? (if you don't have any private file in your working tree)

Comment: Makes no difference, @VonC.

Comment: I'm suffering with this exact same problem on Xcode 5 too. I wish there was a way to resolve this. I need to switch back to a local branch to continue development.

Comment: Try the `-f` flag for "force", for example `git checkout -f master`

Answer (score 76):

Okay, so I fixed my issue.

With Xcode open:

1. Open terminal - cd / to your project directory.
2. Type in: "`git reset --hard`"
3. Type in `git status`

Restart Xcode and make a commit (Just a comment or something )

Repeat the above steps.

This sorted out my issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Tander. As suggested up in the comments on the question, however, that doesn't fix my problem...

Comment: In my case,  the "git reset --hard" step was sufficient to fix the issue. Thank you @Tander

Comment: No problem @Kqtr - surprisingly, 4 years later and this is still and issue in the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Every time I clicked something in Xcode it changed my userdata file, so I had to `git reset --hard` after every move to the unstashing action. In hindsight, maybe I only needed to do the reset right before unstashing, but for everyone else's awareness, changing views in Xcode or clicking on UI will refresh your IDE and update your userdata file.

Answer (score 8):

You must fix it with command line git. Go to your working folder in Terminal, type:

```
git status
```

That will show you what files have uncommitted changes. Crashlytics, for instance, will update itself as soon as you run it, and even using Xcode/Source Control/Discard Changes won't get rid of it.

Once you see the files that have uncommitted changes (ignore added files), use:

```
git checkout -- Folder/filename.ext
```

That's the same as a "discard" in Xcode.

After you've done that, go back to Xcode and you should be able to switch branches.

Answer (score 3):

xCode is really-really crappy. Everytime you just look at files, a file called UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate is changed. You don't see it in the overview of xCode itself, through the command line you can.

Quick fix:

1. Open Terminal
2. CD to your project directory, and type the following:
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "Commit"`
5. `git push origin master`

Comment: How can we exclude the file?

Comment: @JCutting8 Idk, i should not recommend it, maybe your UI is gone than

Answer (score 0):

App Code solution:

1. Confirm git status in Terminal:

   git status
2. Open 'yourProject.xcworkspace' in [App Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)
3. VCS > Git > Branches...
4. Remote Branches > yourBranch > Checkout as new local branch
5. Confirm fix via Terminal:

   git status

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1:

```
git rm --cached ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Step 2:

```
git commit -m "Removed file that shouldn't be tracked"
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer did not work for me unfortunately because I had untracked git files.

To fix this, go to your working folder in Terminal, type: `git status`

That will show you files that are not being tracked by git. Now add each file with:

```
git add <file with location>
```

You should be able to copy/pasta the file with location from what gets printed out from `git status`.